# How to fetch selected value of button using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have following code for search bar where there is a Drop down list which I have developed on button and a text field to type search query.

On button click I am retrieving text using

```
document.getElementById('').value;
```

But how can fetch selected text of drop down button?

My code :

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >
            <span id="search_concept">T Shirts</span> <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#its_equal">Watches</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="niket" placeholder="Search term...">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="apply"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add `click` listener on the dropdown menu items, and save the selected item text in a variable. Then use this variable when the user click on the **Apply** button

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap. Bootstrap components often require jQuery. Use jQuery to bind a click handler to each of the dropdown items you want to retrieve a value from, in this case the `<a>` tags.

You can store that value in a variable and retrieve it when the search button is click.

```js
(function(window, document, $, undefined) {

  var dropdownValue;

  /* Search dropdown menu for items that hold values we want, ".dropdown-menu a" */
  $('.dropdown-menu a').each(function(i, item) {

    /* Add click handler to each one, whenever one is clicked the
       dropdownValue variable is updated with it's value */
    $(this).on('click', function(e) {
      dropdownValue = this.innerText;
    });

  });

  /* Retrieve dropdown value */
  $('#apply').on('click', function(e) {
    alert(dropdownValue);
  });

}(window, window.document, jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span id="search_concept">T Shirts</span>  <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#its_equal">Watches</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#its_equal">Ties</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="niket" placeholder="Search term...">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="apply"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
  </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Another way would be to apply a class to the selected `<a>` tag and query for that when the search button is clicked so you don't have to create a variable and update it.

Comment: I tried to run code snippet of your example, but it doesn't shows me the alert box with selected value.

Comment: What does the Console say? Are there any errors? Have you included it in the appropriate location? i.e. After you have include jQuery and Bootstrap's JS?